# table single column in 2 column article

Tags: tables

anyone have the simplest code for me to use ?

I tried

```
\begin{tabu} to 0.8\textwidth { | X[l] | X[c] | X[r] | }
    \hline
    item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
    \hline
    item 21  & item 22  & item 23  \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
```

but it wrong

this is my code

```
% Template for ICIP-2013 paper; to be used with:
%          spconf.sty  - ICASSP/ICIP LaTeX style file, and
%          IEEEbib.bst - IEEE bibliography style file.
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spconf,amsmath,graphicx}

% Example definitions.
% --------------------
\def\x{{\mathbf x}}
\def\L{{\cal L}}

% Title.
% ------
\title{AUTHOR GUIDELINES FOR ICIP 2013 PROCEEDINGS MANUSCRIPTS}
%
% Single address.
% ---------------
\name{Author(s) Name(s)\thanks{Thanks to XYZ agency for funding.}}
\address{Author Affiliation(s)}
%
% For example:
% ------------
%\address{School\\
%   Department\\
%   Address}
%
% Two addresses (uncomment and modify for two-address case).
% ----------------------------------------------------------
%\twoauthors
%  {A. Author-one, B. Author-two\sthanks{Thanks to XYZ agency for funding.}}
%   {School A-B\\
%   Department A-B\\
%   Address A-B}
%  {C. Author-three, D. Author-four\sthanks{The fourth author performed the work
%   while at ...}}
%   {School C-D\\
%   Department C-D\\
%   Address C-D}
%
\begin{document}
%\ninept
%
\maketitle
%
\begin{abstract}
The abstract should appear at the top of the left-hand column of text, about
0.5 inch (12 mm) below the title area and no more than 3.125 inches (80 mm) in
length.  Leave a 0.5 inch (12 mm) space between the end of the abstract and the
beginning of the main text.  The abstract should contain about 100 to 150
words, and should be identical to the abstract text submitted electronically
along with the paper cover sheet.  All manuscripts must be in English, printed
in black ink.
\end{abstract}
%
\begin{keywords}
One, two, three, four, five
\end{keywords}
%
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

These guidelines include complete descriptions of the fonts, spacing, and
related information for producing your proceedings manuscripts. Please follow
them and if you have any questions, direct them to Conference Management
Services, Inc.: Phone +1-979-846-6800 or email
to \\\texttt{papers@icip13.org}.

\section{Formatting your paper}
\label{sec:format}

All printed material, including text, illustrations, and charts, must be kept
within a print area of 7 inches (178 mm) wide by 9 inches (229 mm) high. Do
not write or print anything outside the print area. The top margin must be 1
inch (25 mm), except for the title page, and the left margin must be 0.75 inch
(19 mm).  All {\it text} must be in a two-column format. Columns are to be 3.39
inches (86 mm) wide, with a 0.24 inch (6 mm) space between them. Text must be
fully justified.

\section{PAGE TITLE SECTION}
\label{sec:pagestyle}

The paper title (on the first page) should begin 1.38 inches (35 mm) from the
top edge of the page, centered, completely capitalized, and in Times 14-point,
boldface type.  The authors' name(s) and affiliation(s) appear below the title
in capital and lower case letters.  Papers with multiple authors and
affiliations may require two or more lines for this information. Please note
that papers should not be submitted blind; include the authors' names on the
PDF.

\section{TYPE-STYLE AND FONTS}
\label{sec:typestyle}

To achieve the best rendering both in printed proceedings and electronic proceedings, we
strongly encourage you to use Times-Roman font.  In addition, this will give
the proceedings a more uniform look.  Use a font that is no smaller than nine
point type throughout the paper, including figure captions.

In nine point type font, capital letters are 2 mm high.  {\bf If you use the
smallest point size, there should be no more than 3.2 lines/cm (8 lines/inch)
vertically.}  This is a minimum spacing; 2.75 lines/cm (7 lines/inch) will make
the paper much more readable.  Larger type sizes require correspondingly larger
vertical spacing.  Please do not double-space your paper.  TrueType or
Postscript Type 1 fonts are preferred.

The first paragraph in each section should not be indented, but all the
following paragraphs within the section should be indented as these paragraphs
demonstrate.

\section{MAJOR HEADINGS}
\label{sec:majhead}

Major headings, for example, "1. Introduction", should appear in all capital
letters, bold face if possible, centered in the column, with one blank line
before, and one blank line after. Use a period (".") after the heading number,
not a colon.

\subsection{Subheadings}
\label{ssec:subhead}

Subheadings should appear in lower case (initial word capitalized) in
boldface.  They should start at the left margin on a separate line.

\subsubsection{Sub-subheadings}
\label{sssec:subsubhead}

Sub-subheadings, as in this paragraph, are discouraged. However, if you
must use them, they should appear in lower case (initial word
capitalized) and start at the left margin on a separate line, with paragraph
text beginning on the following line.  They should be in italics.

\section{PRINTING YOUR PAPER}
\label{sec:print}

Print your properly formatted text on high-quality, 8.5 x 11-inch white printer
paper. A4 paper is also acceptable, but please leave the extra 0.5 inch (12 mm)
empty at the BOTTOM of the page and follow the top and left margins as
specified.  If the last page of your paper is only partially filled, arrange
the columns so that they are evenly balanced if possible, rather than having
one long column.

In LaTeX, to start a new column (but not a new page) and help balance the
last-page column lengths, you can use the command ``$\backslash$pagebreak'' as
demonstrated on this page (see the LaTeX source below).

\section{PAGE NUMBERING}
\label{sec:page}

Please do {\bf not} paginate your paper.  Page numbers, session numbers, and
conference identification will be inserted when the paper is included in the
proceedings.

\section{ILLUSTRATIONS, GRAPHS, AND PHOTOGRAPHS}
\label{sec:illust}

Illustrations must appear within the designated margins.  They may span the two
columns.  If possible, position illustrations at the top of columns, rather
than in the middle or at the bottom.  Caption and number every illustration.
All halftone illustrations must be clear black and white prints.  Colors may be
used, but they should be selected so as to be readable when printed on a
black-only printer.

Since there are many ways, often incompatible, of including images (e.g., with
experimental results) in a LaTeX document, below is an example of how to do
this \cite{Lamp86}.

\section{FOOTNOTES}
\label{sec:foot}

Use footnotes sparingly (or not at all!) and place them at the bottom of the
column on the page on which they are referenced. Use Times 9-point type,
single-spaced. To help your readers, avoid using footnotes altogether and
include necessary peripheral observations in the text (within parentheses, if
you prefer, as in this sentence).

% Below is an example of how to insert images. Delete the ``\vspace'' line,
% uncomment the preceding line ``\centerline...'' and replace ``imageX.ps''
% with a suitable PostScript file name.
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{figure}[htb]

\begin{minipage}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
  \centering
  \centerline{\includegraphics[width=8.5cm]{image1}}
%  \vspace{2.0cm}
  \centerline{(a) Result 1}\medskip
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.48\linewidth}
  \centering
  \centerline{\includegraphics[width=4.0cm]{image3}}
%  \vspace{1.5cm}
  \centerline{(b) Results 3}\medskip
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
  \centering
  \centerline{\includegraphics[width=4.0cm]{image4}}
%  \vspace{1.5cm}
  \centerline{(c) Result 4}\medskip
\end{minipage}
%
\caption{Example of placing a figure with experimental results.}
\label{fig:res}
%
\end{figure}


% To start a new column (but not a new page) and help balance the last-page
% column length use \vfill\pagebreak.
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\vfill
%\pagebreak

\section{COPYRIGHT FORMS}
\label{sec:copyright}

You must include your fully completed, signed IEEE copyright release form when
form when you submit your paper. We {\bf must} have this form before your paper
can be published in the proceedings.

\section{REFERENCES}
\label{sec:ref}

List and number all bibliographical references at the end of the
paper. The references can be numbered in alphabetic order or in
order of appearance in the document. When referring to them in
the text, type the corresponding reference number in square
brackets as shown at the end of this sentence \cite{C2}. An
additional final page (the fifth page, in most cases) is
allowed, but must contain only references to the prior
literature.

% References should be produced using the bibtex program from suitable
% BiBTeX files (here: strings, refs, manuals). The IEEEbib.bst bibliography
% style file from IEEE produces unsorted bibliography list.
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}
\bibliography{strings,refs}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either `0.8\linewidth` or `0.8\columnwidth`:

```
\usepackage{tabu}

%...

\noindent
\begin{tabu} to 0.8\columnwidth { | X[l] | X[c] | X[r] | }
  \hline
  item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
  \hline
  item 21  & item 22  & item 23  \\
  \hline
\end{tabu}
```

You can also obtain the same result using [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx):

```
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

%...

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\columnwidth}{ | L | C | R | }
  \hline
  item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
  \hline
  item 21  & item 22  & item 23  \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
```